# Accessing Sharepoint using "Ruby on Rails" framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sharepoint-2013, vmware

I have installed sharepoint2013 on vmware9.0.1 and also i have uploaded some sample documents into it. Using ruby i want to interact thoese documents which were in sharepoint2013. I have come across many links in the google but i didnt get any absolute answer. Can anyone suggest me how to get through it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading Martin's answer, I've implemented a gem that implements the REST API for Sharepoint. It's not completely exhaustive, but it's enough for most of the tasks.

You can check out the gem over there:
https://github.com/Plaristote/sharepoint-ruby

Comment: Thank you sir..Can you share me the gem name exactly to keep it in Gemfile :) @Michael

Comment: It's `sharepoint-ruby`, in a Gemfile you'd install it by using `gem 'sharepoint-ruby', github: 'Plaristote/sharepoint-ruby'`. Then you'd go `require 'bundler/setup'` and `require 'sharepoint-ruby'`.

Comment: Ya surely i will do sir. Thank you :)

Comment: @Michael can you please how to get all items in a list. I have 3000 items in a list but list.items only give 100

Comment: @Michael list.items only give me first 100 items while list.item_count is 3000 how can i iterate over all other records. Please help me

Comment: I haven't yet been faced with lists containing so many items. I can't find any mention of it in the database, but it wouldn't be surprising if the API prevented you from requesting so much items at once. You probably have to use the $skip and $top parameters. Which means I probably should add a method to get the items. You should probably create an issue on the github (I can't get on it right now).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Sharepoint is exposing a nice REST API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx#Reference). Based on this, you should be able to call it easily using a simple rest client such as [rest-client](https://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client).

Should your work be extensive, maybe you could extract a part of it in a sharepoint-api gem. I'm sure this would be useful to other people.